# ¿Cómo ejecutar una macro .xlsm desde python?

Tags: python, excel, macros

espero se encuentren bien. Estoy intentando correr una macro de excel por medio de código desde python, sin embargo, recibo siempre este error:

```
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Ocurrió una excepción.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'No se puede ejecutar la macro "B:\\WFM - Compartida Lima\\02.Proceso 6 Dias\\Revision dias Consecutivos_v2.xlsm!Módulo2.Import". Puede que la macro no esté disponible en este libro o que se hayan deshabilitado todas las macros.', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)
```

no sé sinceramente que pasa, porque el archivo sigue en la ruta, estoy poniendo correctamente el nombre de la macro y el modulo y aun asi no funciona. tengo el siguiente código

```
import os, os.path
import win32com.client
if os.path.exists('B:\WFM - Compartida Lima\\02.Proceso 6 Dias\Revision dias Consecutivos_v2.xlsm'):
    Excel_macro = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") 
    Excel_path = os.path.expanduser('B:\WFM - Compartida Lima\\02.Proceso 6 Dias\Revision dias Consecutivos_v2.xlsm')
    workbook = Excel_macro.Workbooks.Open(Filename = Excel_path, ReadOnly =1)
    Excel_macro.Application.Run('B:\WFM - Compartida Lima\\02.Proceso 6 Dias\Revision dias Consecutivos_v2.xlsm!Módulo2.Import') 
    workbook.Save()
    Excel_macro.Application.Quit()  
    del Excel_macro
```

si me pueden ayudar a encontrar la forma de que funcione o alguna otra forma de ejecutar una macro desde python, se los agradecería full. de antemano gracias